# Partitioning Data for Multiple Regression Lines

Tags: optimization, regression, partitioning

We're all familiar with traditional least-squares method for constructing a straight line through a set of data points. The question is: suppose I show you a scatter plot which clearly is suggestive of more than one line (suppose two). I need to split the data points into two groups and build a regression line for each.

How do I split the dataset into two so groups so as to make optimal split? What if I allow to leave out some data points entirely from either dataset? Is there a formal name for this problem in research? Are there any known solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of data you're talking about. E.g., do you mean two lines that overlap or that you want to make a piecewise approximation with two lines of differing slopes? Or something else?

Comment: It's really very simple. Imagine you're given a textbook-like example of points which just beg to have a straight line drawn through them. Then just duplicate that set of points but move their y coordinate somewhat. Now you have two sets of points, both sets can have a straight line drawn through them. Unfortunately if you now try to draw a straight line though this combined set of points, you'll have a problem - there is no one line that can be nicely drawn through this combined set of points.

Comment: My question is general: what do we qualify this problem as? The problem is, given a set of points and a count of lines, the algorithm should split the points in such a way that optimizes regression line building (this is not an academic description, but I hope you get the point). I am sure there is no right way to do it - so some points may be even left out.